# i want sql code to run a report that alculate percentage per manager for employees who accepted compliancetype

Tags: sql-server

I have employee,manager,complincetype tables which i would to calulate how many employees have accepted what kind of compliencetype.compliancetype table consist of the following columns i.e bcoe,eud,leave,building,parking so in each manager there can be 2 or more employees that accept bcoe,so whats the percentage for that manager in bcoe depending how many employees under that manager.i have managed to join manager and employee table so that i can see who reports to which manager,so i need sql code to join all tables and calculate the percenatge.in compliancetype table i have 'y' as data under each compliencetype to indicate that such employee accepted that complience.i have emp_id column on the complience table as well to indentify employee.

table columns as follows:manager table:manager_id as PK,name as char,lname as char
employee table:emp_id as PK,emp_name,emp_surname,manager_id
compliencetype table:bcoe,eud,leave,building,parking,emp_id

i'm running this report on oracle apex

Comment: i have joined on 3 tables and can view which employee belongs to which manager but i'm stack now to calulate the percentage,

Comment: Please include your query where you joined the three tables.

Comment: Also, which version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: select c.cmanager_id,c.cmanager_name,bcoe,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_lname from cemployees e join cmanager c on c.cmanager_id = e.cmanager_id join compliancetype t on e.emp_id = t.emp_id   it's sql11.1

Comment: i believe i have to count the total of emp_id under that manager,then count the emp_id that is y under that manager then divide emp-

Comment: i believe i have to count the total number of emp_id under that manager,then count the ones that = y,divide y emp_id by total number of employees per manager *100 ||"%"

Answer (score 0):

Without actual data to test with, I'm guessing a little here, but possibly something like this:

```
select c.cmanager_id,c.cmanager_name,bcoe,e.emp_id,e.emp_name,e.emp_lname 
, pct = 100 * SUM(CASE bcoe WHEN 'Y' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)OVER(PARTITION BY c.cmanager_id)
  / SUM(1.0)OVER(PARTITION BY c.cmanager_id)
from cemployees e 
join cmanager c on c.cmanager_id = e.cmanager_id 
join compliancetype t on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
```

My actual test query for the percent formula:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cmanager_id
, pct = 100 * SUM(CASE bcoe WHEN 'Y' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)OVER(PARTITION BY c.cmanager_id) / SUM(1.0)OVER(PARTITION BY c.cmanager_id)
FROM (VALUES(1,'Y',8),(2,'Y',8),(3,'N',8),(4,'Y',9),(5,'N',9)) c(emp_id,bcoe,cmanager_id)
```

Result:

```
cmanager_id pct
----------- ---------------------------------------
8           66.666666
9           50.000000
```